# Python development with Emacs?

Tags: python, emacs

Anybody knows some actual documentation written? I can't find anything good for any of the 2 competing modes. Looks like Emacs is pretty much abandon when it comes to Python and it is a shame as there is no other programmable programming editor that comes close to Emacs.

Comment: You know that the last sentence is going to get you flamed? I mean, EVERYONE knows that Emacs is for wimps, Real Programmers use Vim ;^).

Comment: Abandoned? Hardly. I think it's just the case that most emacs users don't need any python-specific documentation. The python mode works pretty much like every other mode. So, c-h m (describe-mode) is usually sufficient.

Comment: Latest change to python-mode.el was made two days ago https://code.launchpad.net/~python-mode-devs/python-mode/python-mode . Though discussion on python-mode list is not very active (should it?) http://blog.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.python-mode

Answer (score 7):

This blog recently had a 2 part series that I found very helpful. [Part 1](http://jesselegg.com/archives/2010/02/25/emacs-python-programmers-part-1/) [Part 2](http://jesselegg.com/archives/2010/03/14/emacs-python-programmers-2-virtualenv-ipython-daemon-mode/)

There was also an article in Python Magazine last year in either November or December that included decent step by step instructions on how to setup Emacs for Python development. That's by subscription only, but it's very similar to [this](http://www.enigmacurry.com/2008/05/09/emacs-as-a-powerful-python-ide/).

My current setup (roughly based on the above but trimmed down) is  PyMacs+Rope+flymake calling pyflakes and pep8 and I find that to be sufficient. You may also find yasnippets useful, though I don't. Though you may want to configure ecb and maybe cedet for some code browsing things. I don't, because then it takes about as long to startup as eclipse.

Nonetheless, there's plenty of resources on the net for configuring Emacs to be a fine Python development environment.

Answer (score 5):

Justin Lilly presented on [editors at PyCon 2010](http://us.pycon.org/2010/conference/schedule/event/129/). His [config](http://github.com/justinlilly/jlilly_emacs) is on GitHub.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you looked in the wrong places?  Did you try

- [the Emacs Wiki page for Python modes](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/PythonMode)
- [the Python Programming in Emacs page](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PythonProgrammingInEmacs)

on the Emacs Wiki?

Comment: I tried:
(RichardRiley  : this is a very, very confusing page. It’s hard to make head nor tail of what could and should be used in emacs 23 and I will try to annotate/clip this page when I know more. The whole python.el v python-mode.el thing is really messy)

Comment: And the second link?  And if they are confusing, could *you* engage with the other contributors to make it a better page?

Comment: The second link has information copied from the first link and only adds to the overall confusion. 
"I’ve copied most of the stuff from PythonMode so as not to disrupt that page with major edits, but I figured the Python page needs breaking up, and more structure added to settle confusion; recommendations anyone? The stuff below needs confirmations as to which of python/-mode/.el they are appropriate for. – CH"

Comment: Well it could have helped if you had been a tad more specific in your question about what you had or had not seen, and what you were or where not expected.

Comment: use python.el, it integrates better with standard emacs features

Answer (score 2):

I started off doing Python development using the setup documented at [Ryan McGuire's tab completion page](http://www.enigmacurry.com/2009/01/21/autocompleteel-python-code-completion-in-emacs/) and sort of branched out from there.  Right now, I have extensively extended and patched that setup up, but it's a pretty good place to start.  If you're moderately emacs-capable and have a bit of python chops this will get you 95% of the way there, with maybe some flakiness in the autocompletion part of the page due to bitrot. I've worked around most of those bugs over time, but it can be a bit of a pain.

I use the launchpad `python-mode` -- the one that does *not* come with Emacs, for what it's worth; I've found that it just suits the way I think about things a bit better, which leads me to think that I've got more of a pythonic bent than an emacs one. Someone commented above that the included python mode is more emacs-like, and they're not wrong.

The wiki page is, as noted, confusing as hell.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice description of the use of elpy, flycheck (autocompletion, syntax check, virtualenv), integration with jupyter notebook, git and other:
https://realpython.com/blog/python/emacs-the-best-python-editor/